# Refresh functionality In Appium

Tags: appium

I want to verify Refresh functionality of App. For this, i have to perform pull down operation rather than click on refresh button. How to do that.  I am using Appium.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `swipe` method as it is marked [deprecated](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/ec9f586934b9c4931b43dd429b7aea1133d3a73b/README.md) and will be removed any time soon
Instead you should use [TouchActions](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/Touch-actions.md):

```
Dimension screenSize = driver.manage().window().getSize();
new TouchAction(driver)
  .press(screenSize.getWidth()/2, (int) (screenSize.height * 0.2))
  .waitAction(500)
  .press(screenSize.getWidth()/2, (int) (screenSize.height * 0.8))
  .release()
  .perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is code for swipe:

SYNTAX : driver.swipe(startX, startY, endX, endY, duration);

```
driver.swipe(400, 800, 400, 200, 2000);
```

Comment: Yes got it. I have to scroll Up Only. Thanks

Comment: Can you please mark this answer as "accepted" if it worked for you. It will be helpful for others.